# Converting between relational calculus and relational algebra

Tags: calculus, relation-algebra

So I'm trying to get my head around relational algebra and calculus and converting between them. I understand that...
$$\{ x\mid\exists y.F(x,y) \wedge G(x,y)\}$$
...equates to $\pi_A F \cap G$

But what about when one of the relations has only a single attribute? Does this affect anything? i.e.
$$\{ x\mid\exists y.F(x,y) \wedge G(y)\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**No, I really think it's different.**

For instance, let's assume we are working in a bank and we have two relationships `Account(Name,balance)` and `Client(Name,balance)`

Let's assume that the balance of a client is unique: it is the sum of the balance of its accounts.

$$\{Name| \exists Balance \ Account(Name,Balance)\wedge Client(Name,Balance) \}$$
Would Give the name of every clients that have a balance equal to the exact sum of one of their account.

Whereas

$$\{Name| \exists Balance \ Account(Balance)\wedge Client(Name,Balance) \}$$

Would give the name of every client that have a balance equal to the exact amount of one of **any** account. (Am I mispelling?)